# Django -- Latest related status record for each object in a single queryset (large data set)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, django-queryset

[edit: Using Django 1.9 & MySQL 5.6; doesn't have a DISTINCT ON keyword]

I've got two models roughly equivalent to the following:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    vin = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...  # lots more not-interesting fields


class Status(models.Model):
    """The status of a vehicle at a moment in time"""
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, related_name='status')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    time = models.DateTimeField()

        class Meta:
            order_by = ('time',)
```

How can I use a **single query** to return the current status of every vehicle? There are hundreds of vehicles, and hundreds of thousands of Status records.

Looping over every vehicle and selecting its latest status is waaaaay too slow for the number of vehicles (hundreds) and statuses (hundreds of thousands).

I tried using .annotate() and .values() to do this; Why doesn't this work? I would expect this to return a cartesian product 
of Vehicle and Status tables, then filter out all but the most recent status.

```
vehicles = Vehicle.objects.annotate(
    status_time=F('status__time'),
    status_time_latest=Max('status_time'),
    status_code=F('status__code'),
).filter(
    status_time=F('status_time_latest'),
).values()
```

Instead, Django's (1.9) seems to be returning only the *first* status code for each vehicle (ordered by ID).

Is this what `select_related()` is for, or would that wind up transmitting the entire Status table over the wire? It's way too big to dump every time I need to run this query; I'd rather offload the processing to the database server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a mix of [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) and [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) to achieve what you want:

```
vehicles = Vehicle.objects
               .annotate(status_time=F('status__time'), status_code=F('status__code'))
               .order_by('id', '-status_time').distinct('id')
```

**Breaking it down:**

```
# first annotate all vehicle objects with all the statuses
vehicles = Vehicle.objects.annotate(status_time=F('status__time'), status_code=F('status__code'))

# order by id, and in decreasing order or status_time
vehicles = vehicles.order_by('id', '-status_time')

# get distinct using id, this will make sure that the first entry for 
# each Vehicle is retained and since we ordered in decreasing order of
# status_time within each vehicle the first entry will have latest status
vehicles = vehicles.distinct('id')
```

Comment: Great idea in theory, but I get "NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend" using MySQL 5.6

Comment: That's my bad. I should have noticed `mysql` tag. Though this works beautifully in postgres.

Comment: Nah, it's cool. I'll add this to the growing list of reasons to switch to PostgreSQL, right up there with native JSON field type for arbitrary data structures. For the moment, I'm stuck with MySQL, so I'll be looking for other solutions, but this is a great answer for somebody with the right tech stack.

Comment: Would it work for you if we could do it in two queries?

Comment: Yeah, two or three queries is fine; I'm mostly trying to avoid a separate query for each vehicle.